# axios ignores false value in request header while doing PUT operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios, http-headers

I am trying to pass Boolean variable in the request header of axios like below,

```
const var = (data, env, isRetry = false) =>  axios.put(url, data, {
   headers: {
   locale: navigator.language,
  'request-id': new Date().getTime().toString(),
   Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
   isRetry: isRetry //true or false
}
});
```

but when isRetry variable is false, it's not appearing in header. Is there any way we can send the false value in header?

```
axios-version: 1.1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

axios is ignoring headers with `false` values, this might be a bug, since it's not documented anywhere

Just set `isRetry: isRetry` to `` isRetry: `${isRetry}` `` to convert it into a string. Header values are always strings, so this shouldn't break anything